# Typescript make a property optional based on value of another property

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and I couldn't find any solutions for below scenario. Any suggestion will be greatly helpful.

I would like to make the property `options` optional if `type` is `SHORT_TEXT` or `LONG_TEXT`.

```
export interface Question {
  [keyName: string]: any;
  type: QuestionType;
  id: string;
  label: string;
  helpText?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  value?: string;
  options?: Option[];
  validations?: any;
  required?: boolean;
  priority?: number;
  intent?: Intent[];
}

export type QuestionType =
  | "DROPDOWN"
  | "CHECKBOX"
  | "RADIO"
  | "SHORT_TEXT"
  | "LONG_TEXT";

export interface Option {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  value?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a ["Discriminated Union"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions). Essentially as you described it: the value of a particular property can be used to narrow the type in a union, and in this case you want one (or more) types where the `options` property is required, and one type where it is optional.

```
export type QuestionType =
  | "DROPDOWN"
  | "CHECKBOX"
  | "RADIO"
  | "SHORT_TEXT"
  | "LONG_TEXT";

export interface Option {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  value?: string;
}

export interface Intent {};

export interface BaseQuestion {
  [keyName: string]: any;
  type: QuestionType;
  id: string;
  label: string;
  helpText?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  value?: string;
  validations?: any;
  required?: boolean;
  priority?: number;
  intent?: Intent[];
}

export interface TextQuestion extends BaseQuestion {
    type: "SHORT_TEXT" | "LONG_TEXT";
    options?: Option[];
}

export interface OptionQuestion extends BaseQuestion {
    type: "DROPDOWN" | "CHECKBOX" | "RADIO";
    options: Option[];
}

export type Question = TextQuestion | OptionQuestion;


const q: Question = {
    type: "SHORT_TEXT",
    id: "id_foo",
    label: "Test Question",
};
```

You can try this out in the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCKBXYBnGBLCAOwBVlUBeAWACg44AfOAIgBEAlAeQAUWOB1AHJMadRkwDCACQCi4gNIAhDgA1htBszYBBFgEkOa0cwDKkjm2IB9YtOXFDGpgBkOAgOLXb9gNw0aoSFg4PEIYYCgAMwBDAGNUDjB8IjgAbxFggBMALjhcKBCAc191ABsogCNgEpy8wuK6ADcokqwAfhqYfMIimgBfP2oA6HgQsMjY1F1Q4FDU3uL-cGHg6fG4uAUo7GBMHCTCVPSAbQBrYEQBKIBbYA6ugoBdHKjCRHqEMhzd3AISMne8Nlcp06ukypVqsD7u8ABZVMDEUAwdpQ0HqMBlOIwiAlDLhFG1brvJotYAEkFE9IkwFRfbYFEvN7pKDAACOGDwLIyKPKEBxwBe7zA+WgeCQKMIGCulSgAOmoRRUzCoSOD2K-Woi0CI1W0XWiJAMG++zgSJmGWwGy2OywP2SaXUdCQKByTFM5isNjsTEcLncnm97zoEESv3pOQS+1V6oGQyCo3CevioaIxt+psN5stm22aft6Sdn2Y7G4vEEPrEUlkihUFc0On0TCDcBDdIjKcI0b6saWQWdqDzB3IcANRttJsYkd+g4WmuoMSIuDgrK+4-Tw4ddELLpMZgsAfsABoC5lXYDLBE+Uxj464OCqq7EUvB9e+sUgA): you'll see that the validator doesn't have an issue with the `q` object, even though it doesn't have an `options` property. But if you change the `type` property on `q` to be `"DROPDOWN"` or something other than `"SHORT_TEXT"` or `"LONG_TEXT"`, the validator will raise an error.

You'll also notice that if you type `q` in the interactive playground, the hint will have it cast as a `TextQuestion` rather than a `Question`, since the type has been narrowed. At least in this example, that actually prevents you from changing the `q.type` property later, but keep in mind that guard will only in blocks where the type of that union has already been narrowed. If you're looping over a list of questions, for example, and you reassign the type:

```
(questions as Question[]).forEach(q => {
  q.type = "DROPDOWN";
});
```

Typescript hasn't narrowed each object's type in this case, and won't guard against you reassigning the `type`.

Hope this helps! ✌️